# How to force a C# root namespace throughout project files for when none is coded?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces, global-namespace

I want to force a root namespace on the contents of any .cs source files that don't have their contents wrapped in an explicit `namespace`. In other words I want to keep classes and other namespace-level structures out of the default namespace.
(Working inside a Windows .NET environment with Visual Studio)

In the following example, I want to force the `Car` class into the `MotorIndustry` namespace by default even though it has no explicit namespace coded.

**Vehicle.cs** (has namespace)

```
namespace MotorIndustry {
    public class Vehicle {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Car.cs** (no namespace/default)

```
public class Car : Vehicle {
    //...
}
```

**Is there a way to accomplish this "root namespace" modification behaviour through project settings in Visual Studio, AssemblyInfo.cs file or some other means?**

My understanding is VB.NET has a feature like this but C# acts differently?

Some context about why am I asking this: I have hundreds of classes and the programmer forgot to wrap the namespace around some. When I reference the assembly from other projects it's polluting the default namespace with classes that end up causing some ambiguous situations.

Comment: No, there is not the ability to globally namespace class files in C# as there is in VB.NET.

John has your answer: third party refactoring tools.

Comment: I think the unique case of a Website project in Visual Studio (not a Web Application) tends to not generate namespaces for classes written under the App_Code special folder, or at least for user controls and pages, and I think this is where the problem started. Anyway, I've started wrapping everything in explicit namespaces even the user controls .ascx and asp.net pages for a more "strongly-typed" access to everything. It's much more manageable as the project grows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ReSharper to move the classes into the proper namespace. In fact, version 5.0 (still in Beta) allows you to correct namespaces globally.

---

The other way to do it is to make the other developer fix the code.

Comment: +1 @John: I'd make the other dev fix the code (*hint hint*) and run ReSharper anyway.

Comment: +1 don't try to accomodate a bad developer's sloppiness. next you'll need to find a way to make C# a case-insensitive language.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are trying to replicate VB.Net's project namespace feature in C#.  This is not a supported feature of the C# compiler or IDE.  You will not be able to create one by modifying a project file.  You will need to add the namespace to every file in the project either manually or via a tool.